# Package_added intent received but apk not found

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to install a new apk from system application using package manager.
After running session.commit, i receive the package_added intent. The new apk exists under /data/app but it doesn't appears in apps menu and even the package name doesn't exist if i start pm list packages command.
I'm using Android 10.

Answer (score 0):

it might not support the app version of android version?

Comment: The same apk was well installed using adb install.